# Querying Postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to query a database where a column matches a string & this string is having a single quote character '. I am unable to run the following query

```
SELECT * 
from <table> 
where <column>='robocopy'w (ithout)backup.pcap';
```

The reason being that single quotes is used to search the column;
I tried double quotes but no help.
I can by pass this if I add a extra single quote just before the single in a string.

```
SELECT * 
from <table> 
where <column>='robocopy''w (ithout)backup.pcap';
```

But I need a better solution as it is not practical to add a single quote every time,specially if they are long and have many single quotes.

Comment: How do you run this? From within a program? If yes, which programming language? Do you pass the search value as a parameter? How do you pass that search value? Where do you get it from?

Comment: yes from a perl script , and yes search value is a paramater that I read from a file and put it in this query using a variable.

Comment: The probelm is not that I run it from a script , I cannot run it directly too.If I can solve this I can modify the script accordingly.

Comment: double dollar solved my problem ..
select path from table where path=$$\Script_test(special_characters)\robocopy'w (ithout)backup.pcap$$;
this works :)
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your query string before sending it to the database.  I can't show you how because you didn't post the code, but if you are running this query directly in the psql console, you can escape the quotes by putting all constraint inside $$ and $$, as cited in the documentation[1].  Example:

```
SELECT * from <table> where <column> = $$robocopy'w (ithout)backup.pcap$$;
```

[1] http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

Comment: No you wouldn't. Single quotes are escaped by doubling them in SQL. `\'` doesn't have a special meaning unless Postgres is configured to accept non-standard strings (and "standard conforming strings" has been the default for quite some time now).

Comment: Thanks chromano for the quick response.
This is column entry which I can query if I give partial path:

select path from <table> where path='%(ithout)backup.pcap%';
                          path
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 \Script_test(special_characters)\robocopy'w (ithout)backup.pcap

Now If I try to search this whole entry It does not run and does not return any error, If I used double quotes instead, it throws a syntax error.

Comment: select path from <table> where path='\Script_test(special_characters)\robocopy'w (ithout)backup.pcap';    r

Note that \ is not an escape character here its part of string in table and if I put a extra single quote before the single quote in my string I can run this query.

select path from <table> where path='\Script_test(special_characters)\robocopy''w (ithout)backup.pcap';
                          path
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 \Script_test(special_characters)\robocopy'w (ithout)backup.pcap
(1 row)

Comment: The reason I posted this is because I am reading the path one by one from a file and I do not know how many times I have single quote in the strings.
So is there any alternate way I do not have to put that extra single quote every time and still query the database ?

Comment: In this case, after checking pgsql docs, I'd go with this solution: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

Comment: That's awesome, Dollar-quoted String Constants resolved my issue.

Comment: This works
select path from table where path=$$\Script_test(special_characters)\robocopy'w (ithout)backup.pcap$$;

Thanks a lot Chromano :)

Comment: @chromano: you should change your answer to use dollar quoting, otherwise this would be misleading.